# Is there a template-like expression in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server, replace

I place the alias values in sql into a string sentence and constantly generate a new string with replace.

But I have to do a lot of "replace" nested this way.

The {{name}} in the string clause is actually the alias in the sql clause

Is there a way to define the sql and template clause and automate it?

Sample:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[message](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [quantity] [float] NULL,
    [delivery] [datetime] NULL,
    [status] [tinyint] NULL,
)
INSERT [dbo].[message] ( [name], [quantity], [delivery], [status]) VALUES ( N'Omer', 124, CAST(N'2022-10-18T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[message] ( [name], [quantity], [delivery], [status]) VALUES ( N'Jacob', 548, CAST(N'2022-11-05T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 0)
INSERT [dbo].[message] ([name], [quantity], [delivery], [status]) VALUES ( N'Hasan', 56454, CAST(N'2022-08-09T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 1)
INSERT [dbo].[message] ( [name], [quantity], [delivery], [status]) VALUES ( N'Hans', 548, CAST(N'2023-11-01T00:00:00.000' AS DateTime), 0)
```

```
4 rows affected
```

```
select * from message where status=0
```

| id | name | quantity | delivery | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Omer | 124 | 2022-10-18 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 2 | Jacob | 548 | 2022-11-05 00:00:00.000 | 0 |
| 4 | Hans | 548 | 2023-11-01 00:00:00.000 | 0 |

```
declare @template nvarchar(max)='Hello, {{name}} todays order quantity {{quantity}} this order must be sent by the latest {{delivery}}.'
print @template

select 
replace(
replace(
replace(@template
,'{{name}}',name)
,'{{quantity}}',quantity)
,'{{delivery}}',format(delivery,'dd.MM.yyy'))
from message where status=0
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| Hello, Omer todays order quantity 124 this order must be sent by the latest 18.10.2022. |
| Hello, Jacob todays order quantity 548 this order must be sent by the latest 05.11.2022. |
| Hello, Hans todays order quantity 548 this order must be sent by the latest 01.11.2023. |

```
Hello, {{name}} todays order quantity {{quantity}} this order must be sent by the latest {{delivery}}.
```

```
declare @template nvarchar(max)='Hello, {{name}} todays order quantity {{quantity}} this order must be sent by the latest {{delivery}}.'
print @template

declare @sqlString nvarchar(max)='select name,quantity,format(delivery,''dd.MM.yyy'') as [delivery] from message where status=0'
print @sqlString
```

```
Hello, {{name}} todays order quantity {{quantity}} this order must be sent by the latest {{delivery}}.
select name,quantity,format(delivery,'dd.MM.yyy') as [delivery] from message where status=0
```

```
/*
template embed code

*/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/amAM01de)

Comment: I was able to get the list of columns but I don't know how to continue.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/BfuImTO7)

Comment: I developed a little more. But it still doesn't give me what I want. My goal is 1 sql statement. Placing the data with 1 template and getting output.
[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5rT1-ZHN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String formatting is a job best done in the application code presentation layer rather than T-SQL. Burdening the database with such tasks limits scalability and hinders performance.

It seems your goal of your fiddle attempt is not only to avoid nested `REPLACE` functions but also a generalized technique to use column names from the query to indicate the values to be replaced in the template (i.e. sniff column names).

A T-SQL recursion technique will avoid nested `REPLACE` functions but performance will be worse. The example below uses a recursive CTE and JSON (instead of XML as in your fiddle). I'm sure there is room for improvement here but it does the job.

```
DECLARE @TemplateString nvarchar(MAX) = N'Hello, {{name}} todays order quantity {{quantity}} this order must be sent by the latest {{delivery}}.';
WITH 
    FormattedValues AS (
        SELECT (
            SELECT 
                  m.id
                , m.name
                , FORMAT(m.quantity, 'N2') AS quantity
                , FORMAT(m.delivery, 'dd.MM.yyy') AS delivery
            FROM dbo.message AS m
            FOR JSON AUTO
            ) AS FormattedValues_json
    )
    ,ColumnValues AS (
        SELECT 
             JSON_VALUE(FormattedValues_json.value, '$.id') AS id
            ,columns.[key] AS ColumnName 
            ,columns.[value] AS ColumnValue
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY JSON_VALUE(FormattedValues_json.value, '$.id') ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS rownum
        FROM FormattedValues
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(FormattedValues_json) AS FormattedValues_json
        CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(FormattedValues_json.value) AS columns
    )
    ,ReplacedValues AS (
        SELECT
              id
            , REPLACE(@TemplateString, '{{' + ColumnName + '}}', ColumnValue) AS ReplacedString
            , ColumnName
            , ColumnValue
            , rownum
        FROM ColumnValues
        WHERE rownum = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
              cv.id
            , REPLACE(rv.ReplacedString, '{{' + cv.ColumnName + '}}', cv.ColumnValue) AS ReplacedString
            , cv.ColumnName
            , cv.ColumnValue
            , rv.rownum + 1
        FROM ReplacedValues AS rv
        JOIN ColumnValues AS cv ON cv.id = rv.id AND cv.rownum = rv.rownum + 1
    )
SELECT ReplacedString
FROM ReplacedValues
WHERE rownum = (SELECT MAX(rownum) FROM ColumnValues); --final string
```